# Encoded URL in Javascript does not show in address bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, urlencode

```
<script>
    function test ()
    {
        var s = encodeURIComponent('a b');
        alert(s);   
        window.location.href = 'http://example.com/?' + s;
    }   
    test();     
</script>
```

The `alert()` shows it was encoded correctly, but address bar shows this `http://example.com/?a b`

[image]

Note: I tested in Chrome and Safari works fine, but not in Firefox?

Comment: Copy and paste the address from the address bar, you'll get your encoded URI again. I am just guessing, but FF probably displays the unencoded version for human readability. Also copying the encoded version into the address bar and pressing enter makes it display the unencoded one again.

Comment: have you tried `window.history.replaceState(null, null, s);`?